# Вывод элемента массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь вывести результаты Ajax запроса:

```
...
success: function(data) {
alert(data);
}
...
```

Всё нормально выводит
{"error":"Вы забыли указать ссылку."}

Пробую вывести отдельно значение:

```
alert(data.error);
```

Выводит: undefined

Пробовал так:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr = data;
alert(arr.error);
```

Результат тот же.

Собственно, прошу объяснить в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас сервер отдаёт данные не в формате JSON, а обычной строкой. Надо или конвертировать в объект, или отдавать данные с заголовком  `application/json`

```
success: function(data) {
  var errors = JSON.parse(data);
  alert(errors.error);
}
```

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!